# White screen after installing django-unfold

Tags: javascript, python, django

I got a problem, it's with JS which we got with the package or with me, which made a mistake on django-side, i'm not sure. I have installed the django-unfold package using "pip install django-unfold" and added it to my INSTALLED_APPS list as follows:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "unfold",
    "unfold.contrib.filters",
    "unfold.contrib.forms",
    # "nested_admin",
    'django.contrib.admin',
    
    # base
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    
    # project apps
    'work',


    # third-party-apps
    'rest_framework',
    'djoser',
    
    # 'corsheaders',
    'django_filters',
]
```

I have also made some changes to my admin.py as shown below:

```
from unfold.admin import ModelAdmin
    
    
@admin.register(Genre)
class GenreAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

However, when I try to access the admin page at /admin/, I am presented with a white screen. Upon checking the console, I found the error message "Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data" in the alpine.persist.js file. I am not proficient in JS but I find the code in this file difficult to understand.

Therefore, I asked ChatGPT to make the code in alpine.persist.js more descriptive. The updated code is shown below:

```
(() => {
  function persistPlugin(alpineInstance) {
    let createPersistInterceptor = () => {
      let key, storage = localStorage;
      
      return alpineInstance.interceptor(
        (componentState, getState, setState, propName, uid) => {
          let stateKey = key || `_alpine_persist_${propName}_${uid}`;
          let storedValue = storage.getItem(stateKey);

          let updatedState = storedValue !== null ?
            JSON.parse(storedValue) :
            componentState;

          setState(updatedState);

          alpineInstance.effect(() => {
            let updatedValue = getState();
            storage.setItem(stateKey, JSON.stringify(updatedValue));
            setState(updatedValue);
          });

          return updatedState;
        },
        (options) => {
          options.as = (newKey) => (key = newKey, options);
          options.using = (newStorage) => (storage = newStorage, options);
        }
      );
    };

    Object.defineProperty(
      alpineInstance,
      "$persist",
      { get: () => createPersistInterceptor() }
    );

    alpineInstance.magic("persist", createPersistInterceptor);
  }

  function isKeyInLocalStorage(key, storage) {
    return storage.getItem(key) !== null;
  }

  function getStoredValue(key, storage) {
    return JSON.parse(storage.getItem(key));
  }

  function saveValueToLocalStorage(key, value, storage) {
    storage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  }

  document.addEventListener("alpine:init", () => {
    window.Alpine.plugin(persistPlugin);
  });
})();
```

And here is the original one:

```
(() => {
  function g(t) {
    let e = () => {
      let n,
        s = localStorage;
      return t.interceptor(
        (r, i, a, p, m) => {
          let o = n || `_x_${p}`,
            l = c(o, s) ? d(o, s) : r;
          return (
            a(l),
            t.effect(() => {
              let u = i();
              f(o, u, s), a(u);
            }),
            l
          );
        },
        (r) => {
          (r.as = (i) => ((n = i), r)), (r.using = (i) => ((s = i), r));
        }
      );
    };
    Object.defineProperty(t, "$persist", { get: () => e() }),
      t.magic("persist", e);
  }
  function c(t, e) {
    return e.getItem(t) !== null;
  }
  function d(t, e) {
    return JSON.parse(e.getItem(t, e));
  }
  function f(t, e, n) {
    n.setItem(t, JSON.stringify(e));
  }
  document.addEventListener("alpine:init", () => {
    window.Alpine.plugin(g);
  });
})();
```

I have attempted to create a new, empty project and install django-unfold there, but the white screen issue persists. I would be extremely grateful if someone could help me resolve this issue